# Vue js trucate property on array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying use Vuejs's vue-truncate-collapsed property to add the read more and read less button. A Worker can have multiple services. Something like this. Services are stored as array.

```
<li v-for="item in worker.service_names">
 {{ item}}
</li>
```

this works perfectly fine. But now what I want to do is display default 5 values(not sure how to add the length of 5) and if a worker has more than 5 services then read more button appear. I am not able to implement this on an array. Please help me figure out the issue. I am new to Vuejs.

```
<truncate
 action-class="action"
 clamp="..."
 :length="5"
 less="read less"
 :text="<li>worker.service_names</li>"
 type="html"
 >
</truncate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over a computed list. If it is a short list the computed value will return a shortened list otherwise the full list.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    workers: ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'],
    showNum: 4,
    short: true
  },
  computed: {
    visibleWorkers(){
      if(this.short){
        return this.workers.slice(0,this.showNum)
      }else{
        return this.workers
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showMore(){
      this.short=!this.short;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="item in visibleWorkers">
      {{item}}
    </li>
  </ol>
<button @click="showMore">{{short?'show more':'hide'}}</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to iterate over the services of the workers rather than the workers themselves. Like in data it has to be over the services of workers something like worker.services

Comment: this is an example of how to do it. I don't know your exact data structure but the principle should hold true

Comment: actually workers table have service_ids which is stored as an array. So I am not sure how to get services in the computed properties.

Comment: in the workers table I am storing service_id this is how I have defined the data structure

Comment: if you want a better answer could you provide a [mcve] of what you have so its not just in the comments, and then my answer can be more specific